# Is it possible for RSA encryption using a public key to have multiple valid results?

Tags: ios, .net, objective-c, vb.net

I am encrypting a string given an RSA public key (in modulus & exponent XML format) on iOS and VB .NET

Same string but the two apps return 2 different encrypted strings, yet both of them are valid and were able to be decrypted by the accepting application. Is this possible?

Comment: More information is required to answer this, like what settings your using to encrypt the data. The obvious answer is yes, it's possible, as you've done it ;) and it's not unusual. They probably have different salts which will generate different encrypted strings.

Comment: Sorry, crypto is a bit foreign for me. For iOS, I am using [CkoRSA](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/objcCkoRsaRef.html) all default settings. For .NET, I'm using the built-in RSACryptoServiceProvider. I don't see any option for different salt. Could it be the different `Charset`? I've tried changing that on iOS to `utf-8` or `Unicode`, both strings are different with .NET version